# React Router Push Silently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

In my case, I have several tabs. The tab container can be swiped. If user switching tab, the route will also be updated. 
For example:

If user is in Tab 1, the route will be `/home`. When he swipes to Tab 2, the route will be `/home/news`. When he swipes to Tab 3, the route becomes `/home/about` And so on.

I'm aware that it can be achieved with `this.props.push(NEXTROUTE)`. But by doing that way, the component is re-rendered and makes me lose the last scrolled position of the previous tab. My case needs to keep that last scrolled position of the tab instead of scrolled over to the top.

Is it possible to push state `silently` in react router? I don't want the component to be re-rendered when pushing state so I can maintain the last scrolled position of the screen.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: how about using `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent render under certain circumstances?

Comment: @azuim I believe a re-render is necessary as the content completely changes. Perhaps listening to the scroll event and saving the scrollTop value somewhere. Even in the localStorage with an appropriate id.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set the routes to point to the same Component and use the route params to set the current chosen tab. This way you achieve the "silent" behaviour you are aiming for:

```
<Route path="/dashboard" component={App}/>
<Route path="/news/:itemId" component={App}/>
```

and:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const { route, params } = props;
    const { path } = route;
    const selectedTab = path !== '/dashboard' ? 1 : 2;

    this.setState({selectedTab})

    console.log('news item -> ', params.itemId)
}
```

A second way is to save the scrolling position and set it back.

A working JSBin: https://jsbin.com/qiraqa/edit?js,output

Relevant code:

```
scroll(e) {

   const { tab, scrollPositions } = this.state;

   const target = e.target,
          scrollTop  = target.scrollTop;

   scrollPositions[tab] = scrollTop;

   this.setState({
       scrollPositions
    });

    console.log(scrollTop);     
}

navigateToTab(tab) {
      const { scrollPositions = [] } = this.state,
      scrollPosition = scrollPositions[tab] || 0;

      this._container.scrollTop = scrollPosition;

      this.setState({tab});    
}
```

and:

```
<div style={MainStyles.overflow} onScroll={this.scroll.bind(this)} ref={(c) => this._container = c}>...
```

This way, you can use the localStorage or a [redux store](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) to persist the scrollPositions array and load it up again after route change.

Note that this example has nothing to do with React Tabs as IMHO, the issue is about saving scrolling position between two navigational states.

**More information**

A tab component, whether it's a [react-tabs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs) or [material-ui's tabs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs), keeps the scrolling position by rendering all tabs and switching the visibility on and off when you move between tabs. It sets the Tab's style to {height: 0, overflow: hidden} and this way keeps the container alive with it's scroll position.

As you mentioned, this doesn't work when you change the root component, the scrolling position will reset when the component reloads. This is probably the proper behaviour, as the route cannot pre-know the side effects of a route change.

To quote Dan Abramov from [this relevant Github thread](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1686):

> ...it's up to you to render your components the same way. For example if you don't cache the data locally, there's nothing router can do to restore your position. But that's how browser's default behavior works, too, we're just trying to emulate it

In other words, according to this paradigm, it's not the router's responsibility and should be done manually.